# How do I fix this wordsearch program?

Tags: c, pointers, wordsearch

I am creating a program without the use of arrays, only pointers, that solves wordsearches. The logic behind my program seems solid, but I am not getting any result when I run it. After finding the word the program is supposed to make the word in the 2D array become lowercase and print out the found word.

The problem I am seeing is that when it prints out the array again after the search is supposed to happen, it doesn't have the lowercase characters and it also isn't printing out the words that are found. I can't figure out why this is happening.

This is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int bSize = 15;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <puzzle file name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    int i, j;
    FILE *fptr;
    char **block = (char**)malloc(bSize * sizeof(char*));
    char **words = (char**)malloc(50 * sizeof(char*));

    fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Open Puzzle File!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<bSize; i++){
        *(block+i) = (char*)malloc(bSize * sizeof(char));

        fscanf(fptr, "%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n", *(block+i), *(block+i)+1, *(block+i)+2, *(block+i)+3, *(block+i)+4, *(block+i)+5, *(block+i)+6, *(block+i)+7, *(block+i)+8, *(block+i)+9, *(block+i)+10, *(block+i)+11, *(block+i)+12, *(block+i)+13, *(block+i)+14 );
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    fptr = fopen("states.txt", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot Open Words File!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<50; i++){
        *(words+i) = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(*(words+i), 20, fptr);        
    }

    for(i=0; i<49; i++){
        *(*(words+i) + strlen(*(words+i))-2) = '\0';    
    }

    printf("Printing list of words:\n");
    for(i=0; i<50; i++){
        printf("%s\n", *(words + i));       
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing puzzle before search:\n");
    printPuzzle(block, bSize);
    printf("\n");

    searchPuzzle(block, bSize, words, 50);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Printing puzzle after search:\n");
    printPuzzle(block, bSize);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void printPuzzle(char** arr, int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
            printf("%c ", *(*(arr+i)+j));
        }
    }

}

void searchPuzzle(char** arr, int n, char** list, int listSize){
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                    searchWord(j, k, n, arr, list, i);
                }
            }

        }

}


void searchWord(int j, int k, int gridsize, char** arr, char** list, int listPos){
    int wordlength = strlen(*(list+listPos));
    if(j+wordlength <= gridsize){ //Horizontal
        int i = 0;
        while(i < wordlength && *(*(arr+(j+i))+k) == *(*(list+listPos)+i)){
            i++;
        }
        if(i == wordlength){
            while(i > 0 && *(*(arr+(j+i))+k) == *(*(list+listPos)+i)){
            tolower(*(*(arr+(j+i))+k));
            i--;
            }
            for(i = 0; i < wordlength; i++)
                printf("%c", *(*(list+listPos)+i));
        }
    }

    if(k+wordlength <= gridsize){ //Vertical
        int i = 0;
        while(i < wordlength && *(*(arr+j)+(k+i)) == *(*(list+listPos)+i)){
            i++;
        }
        if(i == wordlength){
            while(i > 0 && *(*(arr+j)+(k+i)) == *(*(list+listPos)+i)){
            tolower(*(*(arr+(j+i))+k));
            i--;
            }
            for(i = 0; i < wordlength; i++){
                printf("%c", *(*(list+listPos)+i));
            }
        }
    }

    if(j+wordlength <= gridsize && k+wordlength <= gridsize){ //Diagonal
        int i = 0;
        while(i < wordlength && *(*(arr+(j+i))+k) == *(*(list+listPos)+i)){
            i++;
        }
        if(i == wordlength){
            while(i > 0 && *(*(arr+(j+i))+(k+i)) == *(*(list+listPos)+i)){
            tolower(*(*(arr+(j+i))+(k+i)));
            i--;
            }
            for(i = 0; i < wordlength; i++)
                printf("%c", *(*(list+listPos)+i));
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the program does not compile, due to missing function prototypes (and the consequent wrong assumptions by the compiler). One of them `tolower()` only gives a warning because `#include <ctype.h>` is missing but the assumption about types was correct.

Comment: Once you have lowercased a word found in the grid, how will its letters match a search with a different direction? But the pointer approach seems perverse – I would get the program fully working with array notation and *then* convert it to pointer notation.

Comment: Note too that `tolower(*(*(arr+(j+i))+k));` does not lowercase anything: function `tolower()`  *returns* the lowercase value (if any) of the character passed, since it is passed `int` and not a pointer to the character.

Comment: Why is it passing an int to tolower? Isn't it dereferencing into a char? arr is a grid of characters
Also none of the words share the same characters on the grid so trying to match differing cases of letters shouldn't become a program for my purposes, and I'm trying to only lower case after the word is confirmed to wholly match.

Comment: It is passing `int` to `tolower` because the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tolower-tolower-towlower-tolower-l-towlower-l?view=vs-2019) says it does. Almost ***no*** library functions either take or return a `char` type, and this one certainly does not take a `char*` type which could modify the source.

Comment: If I don't use tolower what should I be doing to convert the characters to lowercase? Do I just have to typecast or is it just the wrong way of doing this?

Comment: `myletter = tolower(myletter);`